# win32 socket function not return

Tags: sockets, winapi

I'm debugging a hang up problem in a win32 program. 
The main thread call stack is:

```
ntdll.dll!_NtWaitForSingleObject@12()  + 0x15 bytes 
ntdll.dll!_NtWaitForSingleObject@12()  + 0x15 bytes 
ntdll.dll!_NtWaitForSingleObject@12()  + 0x15 bytes 
kernel32.dll!_LocalBaseRegQueryValue@24()  + 0x215 bytes    
kernel32.dll!_RegQueryValueExW@24()  + 0x107 bytes  
mswsock.dll!_SockLoadTransportMapping@8()  + 0x33 bytes 
mswsock.dll!_SockGetTdiName@40()  + 0x6c9f bytes    
mswsock.dll!_SockSocket@40()  + 0x9f bytes  
mswsock.dll!_WSPSocket@28()  + 0xe3 bytes   
ws2_32.dll!_WSASocketW@24()  + 0x9d bytes   
ws2_32.dll!_socket@12()  + 0x56 bytes   
......
```

It seems that the [socket()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740506(v=vs.85).aspx) do not return so that program hangs up. The arguments passed into socket() are 2,2,17 witch means create an IPv4 UDP socket. And I **do not have the source code** which calls the win32 API.

I had search google but nothing useful found and I have no idea with this bug. There are more information in dump file, but I can not upload it here for some reason. If there is anything not clear, just ask and I will post the related infomation.

BTW, the bug do not appear every time, just about once in every 15000 times running.

Comment: This site is about programming, which requires sourcecode. Since you don't have any, what do you think you can do anyway? Why do you even bother tagging this with "c++" and "visual-c++"? That said, what is your question? You haven't asked any yet!

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt  I know it's bad to ask such a question, but I just do not know what will cause this bug, just give some relate information is very helpful.

Comment: Have you tried doing any research concerning the functions in the backtrace? What are other threads in your executable doing at that moment? It could also be caused by some buggy code writing somewhere in the process' memory space and corrupting some things. Extract a minimal example from the sources to post here. Otherwise, contact the vendor of that binary and tell them to fix the bug.

Comment: I had search every function in call stack but nothing useful found. I think there should be some clues in `_SockLoadTransportMapping` or other functions in call stack, so I ask here. The program is very complex, so contact the vendor would be the best way. Many thanks.

Comment: Can you figure out what the remote address and port is so that you can try a `telnet` to that address?

Comment: @FredrickGauss I had found out the dead lock reason is Heap32Next() using in rand generate in openssl.

Comment: @zzy, Can you describe your solution in the answers? Otherwise mods can delete your question resulting rate loss.

Comment: @FredrickGauss I have post it, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally the problem is that `openssl` will use `Heap32Next` function in `RAND_poll` for rand generation on windows. It will cause deadlock on win7 or other windows(I'm not sure). Anyone can easily find many bug report from google just search `Heap32Next` or `RAND_poll`.

At last, forgive me not giving the source code in question.